# How many spanning trees does a graph obtained from $K_n$ by adding an extra vertex adjacent to two vertices in $K_n$ have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I've tried solving this with the Matrix-Tree Theorem using the Laplacian matrix, and found a result of  $2 \cdot (n-2)^{n-2}$.

However, I feel as if I am approaching this in the wrong way. Any hints on approaching it in a different way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression $2(n-2)^{n-2}$ can't be right, because when $n=3$ you are counting the spanning trees in the [diamond graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_graph) $K_4-e$ and there are $8$ of them, not $2$.

Let's try just using Cayley's formula. Say the new vertex $z$ is joined to the two distinct vertices $x$, $y$ of $K_n$. A spanning tree for the new graph must contain one or both of the edges $xz$ and $yz$.

The number of spanning trees containing $xz$ but not $yz$ is equal to the number of spanning trees in $K_n$, which is $n^{n-2}$. The number of spanning trees containing $yz$ but not $xz$ is the same.

The number of spanning trees containing both $xz$ and $yz$ is equal to the number of spanning trees in the original graph $K_n$ containing the edge $xy$, and that number is
$$\frac{n-1}{\binom n2}n^{n-2}=2n^{n-3}.$$

Thus the total number of spanning trees is
$$2n^{n-2}+2n^{n-3}=2(n+1)n^{n-3}.$$